# How to add other class's components in the value of a property in the state of a components in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, state, loading

**ReactJS:** I'm trying to render a `<ul>` using Reactjs. I've created **2 components, one is for individual `<li>`'s, and other for the `<ul>`**. I did this so that I could handle events / animations individually for each of them. Now I want to **store each `<li>` components in one of the property in the state of the `<ul>` component**. I want this to be done before `<ul>` component would mount. ***When the `<ul>` component will render, all the `<li>` components also should be rendered from the `<ul>` state***. How can I do that?

There are multiple `<li>` components in the `<ul>` state's property! They are supposed to be GET from the server, based on the customer's activity on the web app.

---

I tried this by creating a **function which will call setState of the `<ul>` component, and update the property with the `<li>` components.** But invoking it in render() *gives an warning*

`` Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state. ``

---

**Here's the code**

```
//CartItemLI component is the <li>
class CartItemLI extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
                     ....
                     ....
        };
    }

    render() 
    {
        return(
                     ....
                     ....
        );
    }
}


// Cart component is the <ul>
class Cart extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
                     ....
                     ....


            //products property should store <CartItemLI />
            products: []
        }
    }

    //I tried invoking initItems() in the render(), but it gives the warning
    initItems() {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.state.numberOfItems; i++)
        {
            var products = this.state.products;

            this.setState((prevState, props) => {
                products: products.push(
                    <CartItemLI ....*props*.... />
                )
            })
        }
    }

    render()
    {

        this.initItems();

        // I want {this.state.products} from state
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.products}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't explain why exactly you want to store li in a state. You likely have XY problem.

Comment: I want ul to be dynamic, as customers can delete the li once it's rendered. I also want to animate the deletion process (I am using anime.js for that). I thought maybe storing them in the state and using setState would be better and easier solution for this.

Comment: You need to store data that is used to generate <CartItemLI> (state.products), not <CartItemLI> itself. I see no benefits from storing `<CartItemLI>`, which is basically createElement object. As I said, it's XY problem. Consider reasking the question with the explanation of real problem instead of a problem with expected solution, which was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to push fully formed react components into state, you can just push the values for the li items, storing product properties in state is enough.

Let state store values and let the rendering happen in render.

Handle the rendering in the cart render method like so:

```
<ul>
   {this.state.products.map( productProps => <CartItemLI {...productProps} />}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I understand from your explanation in that you want all the

from CartItemLI Component, right? And for all those

you need multiple  which you want to pass as props from the CartItemLI Component?

```
//CartItemLI component is the <li>
class CartItemLI extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <li>{this.props.lidata}
                <CartItemUL ulprops={this.props.uldata} />
            </li>
        )
    }
}

//CartItemUL component is the <ul>
class CartItemUL extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);       
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>{this.props.uldata}</ul>
        )
    }
}

// Cart component is the <ul>
class Cart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            //products property should store <CartItemLI />
            products: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {

        var sourceOfLI = require('./sampledata/Blank.json');
        var sourceofUL = require('./sampledata/Blank.json')
        this.setState({
            products: sourceOfLI,
            ulData: sourceofUL
        })
    }

    render() {
        // I want {this.state.products} from state
        return (
            <CartItemLI lidata={this.state.products} uldata={this.state.ulData} />
        )
    }
}
```